# Arm-gcc-8.2.0 don't know how to solve the none-return value issue

Tags: c, gcc

There is an interesting issue.
If we don't add the return value in an integer function that maybe the program will hang up or segment fault when running it in embedded devices which based arm gcc8.
But there are different behavior in different compiler version on this issue.
We know the compiler will report a warning that we have not the return value in an integer function.
But it looks like that the cross compiler(8.2.0) don't know the next step after running out the integer function.

GCC-4.5.2
GCC-6.3.0
arm-linux-gnueabi(4.5.2)
arm-ccp-linux-gnueabi(8.2.0)

program running status
Well
Well
Well
Hang up or segment fault

GCC-4.5.2 ----------work well
GCC-6.3.0 ----------work well
arm-linux-gnueabi(4.5.2)----------work well
arm-ccp-linux-gnueabi(8.2.0)----------hang up or segment fault in embedded device

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int a_function_die(int aa)
{
    //    return 0;
}

void *poll_thread(void *arg)
{
    printf("before call a_function_die\n");
    a_function_die(123);
    printf("after call a_function_die\n");

    while(1) {
        printf("I am aliave\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t pid;
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, poll_thread, NULL);
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is valid C99, but not valid C11 (in C99 it's ok to return without a value if the function's return value is not used, but in C11 it's never ok). Try compiling with `-std=c99`. But it would be best to fix your code. Not returning a value in a function that has a non-void return type is ok in C99, but it's bad practice.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you very much. Now I got the principle of this issue.

Comment: @Gilles: What is your basis for asserting it is never okay in C 2011 for a function to return without a value? C 2011, draft N1570, 6.9.1 12 says “If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.” C 2018, official version, says “Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil My bad, I thought this was one of the things that had been removed in C11, but you're right, it wasn't. So @ xmm-wang this is still valid C. It's a bad idea, but the compiler is supposed to handle it correctly.